# Probability of a point randomly chosen in a circle is nearest to the center

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I've been having some trouble thinking about this problem for a couple days, but everything I've done has been useless, can you guys help me?

Inside of a circle of radius A>0, N points are chosen randomly and independently. What is the probability that the distance between the point closest to the center of the circle and the center of the circle itself is at least B>0?

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: think about areas.

Comment: Probability of one point being at least $B$ distance away from centre is $(1 - (\pi * B^2)/(\pi * A^2))$. Probability of all $N$ points being at least $B$ distance away from centre is hence that raised to $N$ which is equal to $(1 - (\pi * B^2)/(\pi * A^2))^N$

Comment: This should be on Mathematics not Mathematica.

Answer (score 2):

Given independent uniform random variables $X,Y$ taking on values in $[0,1]$, points with $\theta=2\pi Y$ and $r=A\sqrt X$ are uniformly distributed in the Cartesian plane, and are in the circle.  There are intuitive explanations of this, for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837572/generate-a-random-point-within-a-circle-uniformly.  A more rigorous proof here is feasible, but perhaps beyond my ability.

Regardless, we can compute

```
Probability[A Sqrt@x>B,x\[Distributed]UniformDistribution[]]
```

which yields a piecewise expression.  We are interested in the case when $A\geq0$ and $B\geq0$ and $A>B$, which Mathematica gives as $1-\frac{B^2}{A^2}$ after a `Simplify`.

A numerical verification of this result may look like

```
With[{A=9,B=5,samples=100000},{N@(Length@Cases[#,True]/Length@#)&[
    Plus@@(#^2)>B^2&/@RandomPoint[Disk[{0,0},A],samples]
  ],N[1-B^2/A^2]}]
```

I digress, the chance that $N$ independent points are all outside the inner disk is $\left(1-\frac{B^2}{A^2}\right)^N$.